# Save new record to different table with button macro

Tags: ms-access, automation, ms-access-forms

I have an Access database and one of my tables is connected a form. I want to delete a record from my table and add it to another table with just one button. Deleting it is simple but I can't find a way to add the record to another table. Do you have any opinion on that?

Comment: Create a query that appends from one table to the other and pass the record id as parameter. Then call the query when the button is clicked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1       Create 2 queries
An insert query
A delete query

2       Create a macro that has three actions

- Open query( To run an append query)
- Open query(To run a delete query)
- A msg box, that will pop up to state that the two queries above ran
  successfully

**N:B**
The insert and delete query will have parameters like record id

```
 Attached is sample of insert query with parameter
```

- The insert query in the macro condition should come first

[image: Macro]
[image: Insert query design view]
[image: Insert query SQL View]